# Android simple file upload

Tags: android, file-upload, android-sqlite, android-volley

Apparently in this world everyone only uploads images to servers, I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to upload a non image file. What I am trying to do is create an sqlite backup file and store it on my server, so that later if the user needs to they can download and use this backup to restore their data.

I have tried the following libraries as well but they don't seem to be working for anything other than an image.

```
implementation "net.gotev:uploadservice:3.5.2"
implementation "net.gotev:uploadservice-ftp:3.5.2"
```

Can someone point me in the direction I need to upload my type of files to a php script so I can store it in my directory?

Comment: Have you try this Fast Android Networking 
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Answer (score 0):

Use [retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make network request, then a simple POST request can be seen here [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)

in a nutshell inside a service you create a function like this

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Part("description") RequestBody description,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
}
```

Comment: This for some reason allows me to upload images, but if it isn't a media type (IE video, png etc) it seems to crash because the file is null and I am trying to upload a `.db` file.

Comment: this should let you upload any type of file, I tried uploading files with different type before, you just have to indicate which type it should accept